# Restrict MATLAB to call functions from same folder as running file

Tags: matlab, function

I am writing a script (lets call it main.m) which calls a function that I wrote (lets call it myfunc.m). It seems I have a few of these myfunc.m functions at different locations on my MATLAB path.

I would like to somehow restrict matlab to only look within the same folder where my main.m class is, when looking for custom functions.

So for example if I have in

```
C:\example\main.m
C:\example\myfunc.m
```

and

```
C:\asd\main.m
C:\asd\myfunc.m
```

and I open `main.m` in folder `example`, when it comes to the call of `myfunc.m`, it can ONLY call a function within folder `C:\example\`. Same goes for if I run `main.m` in folder `C:\asd\`.

I hope this makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Why not to use a normal path without including unnecessary folders?

Comment: Hi, currently this is not possible because I need different versions of this same function file for different code (silly I know but its just how I've done it for now), hence I would like a way to select the file on a case by case basis.

Comment: Then create a function which will update your path based on the version of the function you need. When you need to call function from another folder, update the path, and function will be called from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the short term, a fairly quick solution would be for you to make your `myfunc.m` files into *private* functions that are ahead in terms of precedence compared to regular functions, and can only be called by functions in the same parent folder.

Simply place your `myfunc.m` files in a folder called `private`:

```
C:\example\main.m
C:\example\private\myfunc.m
```

and

```
C:\asd\main.m
C:\asd\private\myfunc.m
```

Now `example\private\myfunc.m` is only callable by things in the folder `example`, and `\asd\private\myfunc.m` is only callable by things in the folder `asd`. In addition, they are higher in precedence than other functions, so you can ensure that the right one always gets called.

Longer term, you might benefit from taking a look at some of the other more extensive ways that MATLAB provides for managing namespace conflicts, such as subfunctions, object-oriented programming, and packages.

Subfunctions are extremely simple to get the hang of. Packages are not at all complicated but require a bit of thought about how to organize your code (which is usually well worth it). OO programming is a much larger change in typical programming style, but for larger applications is pretty essential.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the private folder options. I will have a read about that and some of the other points you mentioned.